# ipyparallel, how to set process numbers of a node

Tags: python, ipython, ipython-parallel

I know I can start my engine by `ipengine --profile=/path/to/ipcontroller-engine.json`. And there are `len(c.ids)` processes.

But, how can I set the numbers of processes running on every remote node? It seems that  `ipengine --profile=/path/to/ipcontroller-engine.json` is just launch just one process on remote machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ipengine` starts one engine (process). If you want multiple engines, you need to call `ipengine` multiple times. One shortcut for this is the `ipcluster engines` command:

```
ipcluster engines -n 4
```

will start 4 engines.

Comment: Is there also a way of specifying this number from within Python?